# querySkuDetailsAsync receives responseCode of -1 while trying to test in-app purchasing for Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on an Android app and would like to have in-app purchases. In order to test these, I have published an Alpha release to only myself. When I try to query the product details, I get a response code of -1, which according to the docs means that the service is disconnected. My relevant code:

```
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getContext()).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase Updated!");
        }
    }).build();

    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(int billingResponseCode) {
            if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Billing setup complete!");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "DISCONNECTED!");
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });

    List skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
    skuList.add("plaque001");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "details response received!");
            Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(responseCode));
        }
    });
```

Every time I open this fragment, I see on the log:

```
details response received!
-1
Billing setup complete!
```

This occurs when I use the Alpha version downloaded from the Play Store, I have a product on the Play Console with ID "plaque001" labelled as active.
What am I doing wrong?
Did I miss a step in setting up and publishing in-app purchases?
How can I test to make sure the products are working correctly?

Comment: Hi Noam! Did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem :/

Comment: I did solve the problem, though I don't remember *exactly* how. Part of the solution was realizing from https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse that the response code of -1 meant that the service was totally disconnected. I don't think it was connecting at all, so it wasn't a code issue, but some larger problem. When I have time later, I will try to figure out exactly how I solved the problem. Hopefully, this will help!

Comment: I'm running into this right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startConnection` is an async call and you are trying to `querySkuDetailsAsync` before your `BillingClient` is connected.

```
mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished ( int billingResponseCode){
        if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Billing setup complete!");

           //TODO query here. (extract into a separate method)
        }
    }
});
```